# Close multiselect dropdown when user clicks outside (different situation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

Please refer to this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/vUSPu/

This is for multi select dropdown. User selects options available in the drop and clicks outside the dropdown menu. The dropdown list doesnt close unless you click on the dropdown menu itself.

Is there any way to hide the dropdown when user clicks anywhere else away from dropdown list.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">    
<dropdown-multiselect pre-selected="member.roles" model="selected_items" options="roles"></dropdown-multiselect>


<pre>selected roles = {{selected_items | json}}</pre>
```

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['app.directives']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){                     
$scope.roles = [
      {"id": 1, "name": "Manager", "assignable": true},
      {"id": 2, "name": "Developer", "assignable": true},
      {"id": 3, "name": "Reporter", "assignable": true}
];

$scope.member = {roles: []};
$scope.selected_items = [];
});

var app_directives = angular.module('app.directives', []);

app_directives.directive('dropdownMultiselect', function(){
return {
   restrict: 'E',
   scope:{           
        model: '=',
        options: '=',
        pre_selected: '=preSelected'
   },
   template: "<div class='btn-group' data-ng-class='{open: open}'>"+
    "<button class='btn btn-small'>Select</button>"+
            "<button class='btn btn-small dropdown-toggle' data-ng-click='open=!open;openDropdown()'><span class='caret'></span></button>"+
            "<ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu'>" + 
                "<li><a data-ng-click='selectAll()'><i class='icon-ok-sign'></i>  Check All</a></li>" +
                "<li><a data-ng-click='deselectAll();'><i class='icon-remove-sign'></i>  Uncheck All</a></li>" +                    
                "<li class='divider'></li>" +
                "<li data-ng-repeat='option in options'> <a data-ng-click='setSelectedItem()'>{{option.name}}<span data-ng-class='isChecked(option.id)'></span></a></li>" +                                        
            "</ul>" +
        "</div>" ,
   controller: function($scope){

       $scope.openDropdown = function(){        
                $scope.selected_items = [];
                for(var i=0; i<$scope.pre_selected.length; i++){                        $scope.selected_items.push($scope.pre_selected[i].id);
                }                                        
        };

        $scope.selectAll = function () {
            $scope.model = _.pluck($scope.options, 'id');
            console.log($scope.model);
        };            
        $scope.deselectAll = function() {
            $scope.model=[];
            console.log($scope.model);
        };
        $scope.setSelectedItem = function(){
            var id = this.option.id;
            if (_.contains($scope.model, id)) {
                $scope.model = _.without($scope.model, id);
            } else {
                $scope.model.push(id);
            }
            console.log($scope.model);
            return false;
        };
        $scope.isChecked = function (id) {                 
            if (_.contains($scope.model, id)) {
                return 'icon-ok pull-right';
            }
            return false;
        };                                 
   }
   } 
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle isn't rendering properly at the moment, sorry.

Comment: Strange, can you please try again ?

Comment: can someone pls confirm if they are able to open the fiddle. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your jsFiddle i see what you mean. I think this would help you.

With a little bit of searching alot can be found :)

[AngularJS dropdown directive hide when clicking outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574365/angularjs-dropdown-directive-hide-when-clicking-outside)

Comment: That's not going to work. As per the documentation, there is no such event to close on select. http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/

Comment: @DinoMyte- As per Dylans link, i get an error probably due to mixing between link and controller. It didnt work somehow. Do you have any suggestions ?:

Comment: The link DinoMyte send me i looked around and found. "closeOnBlur" option the description says : Indicates if the dropdown should close when clicking outside of it's scope.

Comment: @DylanWijnen- do u know how to use it in my fiddle ? i saw one link and they mentioned that they can use closeOnBlur. https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/pull/18

Comment: got it.  $scope.settings = {closeOnBlur: true }

Comment: Thanks Dylan and Dino.