# angular dropdown with checkbox is not closing

Tags: angularjs

I try to created dropdown with checkbox using angular demo, but its not closing if we click outside of select.
can anybody help?

Please find my fiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/jab4raoq/120/

```
HTML:
Below is my html code, please note above fiddle to see the full angular code


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

    <dropdown-multiselect dropdown-title="Select Filter" pre-selected="member.states" model="selected_items" options="states" tabindex="2"></dropdown-multiselect>
    <div>
    focused: {{focused}}
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: please look in to this:  http://jsfiddle.net/jab4raoq/120/

Comment: checkout this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574365/angularjs-dropdown-directive-hide-when-clicking-outside)

Comment: thanks for reference, i try the same way  but the $document.bind('click', function(event) is not firing, can you help: http://jsfiddle.net/jab4raoq/123/

Comment: @Pravesh Khatri:  
thanks for reference, i try the same way but the $document.bind('click', function(event) is not firing, can you help: jsfiddle.net/jab4raoq/123